# Python Import and Global Variables

Tags: python, import, global-variables

Suppose I have a file:

```
# main.py

import foo

my_global = "global variable"
foo.print_global()
```

and another:

```
# foo.py

def print_global():
    global my_global
    print(my_global)
```

Why do I get `NameError: name 'my_global' is not defined` when I run `main.py` please?
How can I make `my_global` available to `foo.py`? Is it a bad idea to try - maybe I should always pass values as function arguments in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have process-wide globals, only module-level globals. `foo.print_global` looks at `foo.my_global`, not `main.my_global`, which is what you set. That is, the scope that `print_global` uses for global variables is determined when `print_global` is *defined*, not when it is *called*.

This would do what you expect.

```
import foo

foo.my_global = "global variable"
foo.print_global()
```

Note that `foo.py` should not rely on someone else creating its global variable(s) before calling `print_global`; at the very least, `foo.py` should initialize `my_global` to `None`, if not some other default value.

Also note that the solution above is *not* the same as

```
from foo import my_global

my_global = "..."
```

This creates a new global name in the current module, which is *initialized* using the current value of `foo.my_global`. The subsequent assignment changes the name of the "local" global variable, not `foo.my_global`.